# Three.js get the 4 corner coordinates of a cube?

Tags: three.js

How do I get the 4 coordinates for the corners of a cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the CubeGeometry (width, height, depth) and you positioned the cube somewhere, then your eight corners are at

```
position.x + width/2, position.y + height/2, position.z + depth/2
position.x + width/2, position.y + height/2, position.z - depth/2
position.x + width/2, position.y - height/2, position.z + depth/2
position.x + width/2, position.y - height/2, position.z - depth/2
position.x - width/2, position.y + height/2, position.z + depth/2
position.x - width/2, position.y + height/2, position.z - depth/2
position.x - width/2, position.y - height/2, position.z + depth/2
position.x - width/2, position.y - height/2, position.z - depth/2
```

Comment: I have tried to set the position of cube2. cube is an array of cubes: cube2.position.set(cube.last().position.x,60,70); but get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'last'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full implementation:

```
// Returns the positions of all the corners of the box
// Uses CSS ordering conventions: CW from TL.  First front face corners, then back.
THREE.BoxGeometry.prototype.corners = function(position){
  this._corners || (this._corners = [
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3,
    new THREE.Vector3
  ]);

  var halfWidth = this.parameters.width / 2, halfHeight = this.parameters.height / 2, halfDepth = this.parameters.depth / 2;

  this._corners[0].set(position.x - halfWidth, position.y + halfHeight, position.z + halfDepth);
  this._corners[1].set(position.x + halfWidth, position.y + halfHeight, position.z + halfDepth);
  this._corners[2].set(position.x + halfWidth, position.y - halfHeight, position.z + halfDepth);
  this._corners[3].set(position.x - halfWidth, position.y - halfHeight, position.z + halfDepth);
  this._corners[4].set(position.x - halfWidth, position.y + halfHeight, position.z - halfDepth);
  this._corners[5].set(position.x + halfWidth, position.y + halfHeight, position.z - halfDepth);
  this._corners[6].set(position.x + halfWidth, position.y - halfHeight, position.z - halfDepth);
  this._corners[7].set(position.x - halfWidth, position.y - halfHeight, position.z - halfDepth);

  return this._corners

}

THREE.Mesh.prototype.corners = function(){

  if (!this.geometry instanceof THREE.BoxGeometry){
    console.warn('Unsupported geometry for #corners()')
    return
  }

  return this.geometry.corners(this.position)

};
```

Comment: Note that you must supply a width, height and depth when defining your BoxGeometry shape.

Comment: Say if you have a cube moving on the x and z axis, and the cube is rotating on all axis, this does not return the correct location of the corner for y. If it y location is not set, it will default to 0, but add the half height for the corner value.