# How to get the exact x,y,z location of all the corners of a cube in three.js

Tags: three.js, rotation, position, vertices

There's [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302603/three-js-get-the-4-corner-coordinates-of-a-cube), but after implementing it, I saw the positions were not true representations of the absolute x,y,z locations of the vertices. I examined the mesh, and looked at the _corners array in the geometry:BoxGeometry property. There I can also find the values. If the cube is rotating on two different axis, and moving on the x and z axis, the y value of the corner position does not change, so these are not accurate values of the x, y and z positions of the corners. I can visibly see the corner positions are moving on the x, y and z axis.

How else can I derive accurate, absolute positions of these corners? So far I cannot find the properties to determine this. Will I need to apply some kind of math using the rotation values with these corner positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to get the [WorldMatrix](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.matrixWorld) of your cube (which contains all transformations) and apply it to a Vector3 with the original vertex positions:

```js
var w = 10;
var h = 15;
var d = 7;

const geom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(w, h, d);
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
const box = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);

// Get world matrix transformation of the box
var boxMatrix = box.matrixWorld;

// Set the initial position of the desired vertex into a Vector3
var vertex = new THREE.Vector3(w / 2, h / 2, d / 2);

// Apply the matrix transformation to the vector
vertex.applyMatrix4(boxMatrix);

// Read the result
console.log(vertex);
```

Comment: Does this give my the x,y,z locations of all 8 corners of the box?

Comment: No, this gives you the location of one corner. You'd need to repeat the same process 8 times with `(+x, +y, +z)`, `(+x, -y, +z)`, `(-x, +y, +z)`, `(-x, -y, +z)`, ...etc to get all eight vertices.